# How to download a timevis timeline from a shiny application

Tags: r, shiny

My timevis timeline is saved inside an object called tv, I then want to give the user to download  the timeline as a .png/.pdf or .html. I got this working outside of shiny but when I try and get it shiny I get the following error: Error in ==: comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types. I did try with "pdf" and pdf but neither worked

My code:

```
      datasetInput <- reactive({
        switch(input$dataset,
               "html" = html,
               "png" = png,
               "pdf" = pdf)
      })


# gives error: comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
      # output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      #   if(datasetInput == "png"){
      #     tv %>%
      #       htmltools::html_print() %>%
      #       webshot::webshot(file = paste(name, filetype, sep="."))
      #   }else if(datasetInput == "pdf"){
      # 
      #   }else{
      #       
      #   }
      # 
      # )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: `downloadHandler` requires 2 arguements: 1. the filename or a function returning the filename and 2. A function telling it how to write to eh given file. I would suggest going over the help file for the funtion and trying `runExample("10_download")` to get an idea of what to do

Comment: `datasetInput` is a reactive, i.e. you use it as a function (without arguments). Its return value is also a device function which will never ever equate a string i.e. `pdf == "pdf"` gives the error you are referring to.

Comment: I read the help documentation and changed it to this: but came up with a file not found page when I clicked download
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    
    filename = function(){
      paste("file1", input$dataset,sep = "")
    },
      
   content = function(file){
    tv %>%
        htmltools::html_print() %>%
        webshot::webshot(file = filename)
   }  

  )

Comment: See [exportwidget](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/exportwidget) by timelyportfolio, timeVis is an htmlwidget and thus can be downloaded as html with `htmlwidgets::saveWidget`